# Buildfire: Locking Screen Orientation

Tags: buildfire

Is there anyway to lock the screen orientation to portrait?
I tried CSS rotate(90) but the side menu still rotates to Landscape.

Comment: This is a current limitation on the BuildFire platform. ITs because BuildFire is an open platform with an open marketplace and not all developers can/will support landscape more. There has been talk about releasing that limitation but the app owner would have to do so knowing that not all plugins will support it.

Comment: A good place to suggest it /up vote it https://suggestions.buildfire.com/